# How does the cartesian product of set A satisfy an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

#### Suppose **A**={a,b,c,d}. Why is **A**×**A** an equivalence relation?

Specifically, how would one show the Property of *Transitivity* simply?

Is it possible to show a*R*b, b*R*c ⟹ a*R*c in this way?

Generally speaking, how is the Cartesian Product of a set like **A** an equivalence relation?

Note: The professor does *not* want me to show *x* ∈ ℝ and the consequence, x − x = 0 ∈ ℤ. He does not want a rigorous proof or anything of the like. Just the intuition.

Comment: The statement $$xRy, yRz\Longrightarrow xRz$$ is true because $(x,z)\in A\times A$. I mean, it's not a consequence of the fact that $xRy $ and $yRz$ but just a fact from the definition of your equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the notations and rigorous definitions.

What you write as $a\,R\,b$ is really defined as $R\subseteq A\times A$ and $\bf{(a,b)\in R}$.

$A\times A$ is the relation where every element is related to every element.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. However, this is an undergraduate introductory discrete math class. I have had a class in proofs far more rigorous than this class, that tends toward analysis. Unfortunately, the professor wants a very simple, intuitive solution here. Assuming the elements are in the reals is not his desire. I want to know if this can be explained intuitively. I understand the more rigorous definition.

Comment: Then the professor should call it a rather self explaining *name*, e.g. the 'all-to-all' relation and  perhaps also avoid the notation $A\times A$.

Comment: Agreed. The class is unfortunately geared toward Computer Science majors more than the mathematics major. The rigor required in my proofs class is simply not welcome in this Discrete Math class. The challenge is posed when I want to apply a known fact from another class, construct a lemma or proof, and he marks "correct, but use this instead". It takes away from the math unfortunately, but I suppose that is what is _required_ for the class.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ A=\{a,b,c,d\}$. $A\times A$ simply has every order pair generated from the elements. So you can prove the Property of Transitivity: Take $a,b,c\in A\times A$. Suppose $(a,b)\in A\times A$ and $(b,c)\in A\times A$. Immediately you have $(a,c)\in A\times A$, because $A\times A$ **includes every pair of elements**.

Bold words may give you some "intuition". In general, any relation on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$.

Answer (score 0):

The cartesian product contains $(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\subset A$. So $aRc$ is always true. Logically speaking, this means $aRb\land bRc\Rightarrow aRc $, but you don't need to look at $aRb$ or $bRc$ to know that $aRc$ is true.